# Бот Python не записывает данные в файл

Tags: python, telebot

После запуска бота (команды /start) бот должен записывать данные в файлы, однако этого не делает, хотя чистая конструкция open - write - close в отдельной программе работает

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(m):
    statistic = open('stat.txt', 'a')
    statistic.write('123')
    statistic.close()
    rassilka = open('ras.txt', 'a')
    rassilka.write('456')
    rassilka.close()
    keyboard = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False)
    keyboard.row('Начать')
    keyboard.one_time_keyboard = True
    bot.send_photo(m.chat.id, photo)
    msg = bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Добро пожаловать, {name}'.format(name=m.chat.first_name), reply_markup=keyboard)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, menu)
```

Comment: Странно. Никаких ошибок не возникает?

Comment: нет, дальше работает полностью корректно, просто не записывает

Comment: А от одинакового пользователя бот запускается и то, что вы просто в отдельной программе пробовали? Может с пермиссиями что

Comment: Проверил. Все прекрасно записывает. 
Скорее всего у вас нет файлов stat.txt и ras.txt.  Файлы открываются с атрибутом 'a' - т.е. на дозапись СУЩЕСТВУЮЩЕГО файла. Если файлы отсутствуют - то и дозаписывать некуда))
P.S. возможно запустили скрипт из другой папки(каталога).

Comment: Вы точно проверяете наличие файлов именно в том каталоге, в котором работает бот?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверте права у бота, возможно он не может создать файл в той дирректории где он находится из-за не хватки прав